# is there any bootstrap frontend structure for php applications?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Recently I start to create some php application. Using bootstrap for frontend design. I want to know is there any bootstrap structure? that for I finish my frontend easily and shortcut. Thank you :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Bootstrap is already a framework for design.  Are you asking if there are pre-made design templates that utilize Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a web framework that focuses only on the front end.

Being a frontend framework is agnostic of the server you use.  It' doesn't care if your backend is PHP, JAVA, PYTHON or whatever.

There are many forks, which enhance the limited amount of colors, controls and other elements.

So the answer is:  Frontend development should be independent of the server,  mainly because it's client side, based on HTNL, CSS and JAVASCRIPT.  Bootstrap itself fulfills frontend needs, but the amount of forks can fulfill what Bootstrap itself lacks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your page's design. For example, if you want a page with a header, the content and a footer, you can make something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <!-- Header -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       ...
     </nav>

     <!-- Content -->
     ...

     <!-- Footer -->
     <footer>
     ...
     </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you want a sidebar, it will be different. You can check for a Bootstrap's templates and use someone that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's late, but anyone who comes here for searching, you can find documentation about the structure from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) Site itself. If you go down to the page you can find some bootstrap examples which you can use for the structure of your design. You can also use the following for the basic structure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

 <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
 <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div id="wrapper" class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8 main-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4 sidebar">
    In reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>

  </div>

 </div><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
     ================================================== -->
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```